# Is there an online encyclopedia of Diophantine equations (OEDE)?

Tags: diophantine-equations

Hello all!

I'm just wondering if there is an online encyclopedia of Diophantine equations (OEDE), analogous to the OEIS for sequences.

While trying to solve one Diophantine equation, I reduced the solution to that of a very similar Diophantine equation with smaller exponents (*i.e.*, almost a descent, but not back to the exact same equation). What I want to do is type in the equation

$$a^2 + b^p = c^2$$

and find references, papers, solutions, *etc.* I know I can Google it, but there appears to be no standard format for equations, so the results are suspect, and what hits I do get are extremely time-consuming to obtain and filter through.

Thanks for any pointers!
Kieren.

Comment: Tito Piezas III has a respectable assemblage.  His site does not have a search feature, but it does have a nice table of contents.  He mght also have a private bibliography.  Gerhard "Has Also Contributed To It" Paseman, 2013.06.14

Comment: Yes, Piezas has a collection of identities, mostly for infinite families of solutions. But he doesn't have much else like statements or proofs of non-existence of solutions.

Comment: Don't know of anything online, but there is Mordell's book, Diophantine Equations, with an index of equations in the back. The book is about 50 years old, but still very useful. Someone should update it....

Comment: You can use Springer LaTeX Search to search for your equation among all Springer journals: http://www.latexsearch.com/#

Comment: But will LaTeX Search find $a^3+b^3=c^3$ if you ask for $x^3+y^3=z^3$?

Comment: A more up-to-date reference than Mordell's book would be Henri Cohen's 2 volume "Number Theory". Perusing through the contents pages you can find very many different Diophantine equations in the text. 

Comment: I'm reminded of this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.3866

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in the comments, Piezas' site [here](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/) has families of infinite solutions for many equations, and some complete characterizations.

There is a thread with a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123592/is-there-a-catalogue-of-solved-diophantine-equations) at math.stackexchange which may be helpful, if you remove the "online" component of your question. The answers in the thread state:

**Diophantine Equations** by Mordell

**The Algorithmic Resolution of Diophantine Equations** by Smart

**Algorithms For Diophantine Equations** by de Weger

**History of the Theory of Numbers, Volume 2** by Dickson

EDIT: Another of the replies said **Number Theory, Volume 1 and 2** by Cohen, but that he had not read either. Since someone just added it to the comments in this thread, I'm now including it here for completeness.

I would add that **An Introduction to Diophantine Equations** by Andreescu, designed for math olympiad training, has many equations and their solutions.

One of the answers in the math.stackexchange thread says "*I imagine a complete catalog and bibliography today, bang up to date but in the same detail as Dickson, would require dozens of volumes and would be more a Wikipedia style project than anything one could reasonably contemplate publishing in book form.*"

This resonates with your online idea, so perhaps someone should initiate it. Certainly it would be very useful, especially to prevent wasting research time on rediscoveries.